# Rootless Docker - non-root container user cannot write to shared volume

Tags: docker

On Ubuntu 21.10 I have installed rootless Docker following the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

My `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` appear to be configured correctly:

```
$ grep ^$(whoami): /etc/subuid
jtreminio:100000:65536

$ grep ^$(whoami): /etc/subgid
jtreminio:100000:65536
```

From my (admittedly shallow) understanding of namespace mapping, I would expect rootless containers to map their internal root user `0:0` to my host's user `1000:1000`. This seems to be the case:

```
$ docker container run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app -w /app bash touch foobar
$ ls -lah foobar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jtreminio jtreminio 0 Feb 11 16:50 foobar
```

However, when I try to use any other user ID within the container, I lose all write permissions:

```
$ docker container run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app -w /app -u 1000:1000 bash touch barfoo
touch: barfoo: Permission denied
```

If I create a directory with permissions set to `777` it seems this works:

```
$ mkdir barfoo && chmod 777 barfoo
$ docker container run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app -w /app -u 1000:1000 bash touch barfoo/foobar

$ ls -lah barfoo/
total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwx 2 jtreminio jtreminio 4.0K Feb 11 16:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 jtreminio jtreminio 4.0K Feb 11 16:51 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1    100999    100999    0 Feb 11 16:51 foobar
```

My confusion here is that the contents of my `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` should be catching this? Am I completely misunderstanding how user namespaces work?

Comment: Why would you expect that any other user should be able to write to a directory where the underlying fs rights for those users is 'r'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no filesystem mapping of uid/gid on files across bind mounts. So the uid in the container will be the same as in the host side of the mount. User namespaces shift those uids in the container, so:

```
$ grep ^$(whoami): /etc/subuid
jtreminio:100000:65536

$ grep ^$(whoami): /etc/subgid
jtreminio:100000:65536
```

Means to map the container uids 0-65536 to host uids 100000-165536 (and the same for gids), so those are the uids in the host you'll see from files created in the container.